# How to count specific string from coulmn (.dat file)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

I am trying to calculate specific string from column [donor, acceptor], I got the result but unable to find all numbers. I want to count the total number occurrence of residues (LYS8-Side, VAL2-Main,.. POPE4-Side, POPE4-Side, ... etc. ) from each column.

Input .dat file.
https://iitbacin-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/20002453_iitb_ac_in/ERCE5FrV6XBNsDneJd4aVuUBX5UVlVZvhh1kudi5vrUl0A?e=6slaUm

Output I am expecting-

Example:

```
donor Number of residues
ASN15- 5
VAL2 - 3
```

Same result expecting for acceptor column.

**CODE I have written.**

```
import pandas as pd

require_cols = [0,1,2,3]
# read by default 1st sheet of an excel file
df = pd.read_table('/home/user/Desktop/Inter_hbond_Peptide_resid_lipid_protein.dat', usecols = require_cols)
df = pd.DataFrame({'donor': ['LYS8-Side'], 'acceptor': ['POPE4-Main'], 'occupancy': [26.27]})
print(df)

# find count 
AA_Count = df.query('donor=="LYS8-side" \
& acceptor=="POPE4-Main"')['acceptor'].count()

print('Number of donor-', end="")
print(AA_Count)
```

Thank You!

Comment: Do you need help reading the table? What is the data format? It's almost impossible to answer your question until you clarify your problem. Second, nobody cares if you've won a Nobel Prize, as long as your difficulty is not about it. Please minimize your question and ask what you require (and what you tried) without stating the rest of your business.

Comment: I am a bioinformatician but cannot understand what you want. What do you want to count? Number of donors for a specific acceptor residue? What is the format of your data? CSV, excel?

Comment: @Vovin Thank you for reply. I have just updated question and input link. Output format is just .dat (contains three column and n number of rows.)

Comment: @StSav012 Thank you for reply and giving your precious time. I have just updated question and input link. Output format is just .dat (contains three column and n number of rows.)

Comment: @Amit The file you've provided helps a lot. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @StSav012 Can you help me to save output  in .xlsx format.

Comment: @Amit, if your problem is to save a `pandas.DataFrame`, use [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) function. If you're saving some custom data, try [`pyexcelerate`](https://pypi.org/project/PyExcelerate/), [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/), or [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to your taste. Oh, `pandas` require `xlsxwriter` or `openpyxl` to export into an Excel book, as far as I remember.

Comment: @StSav012 Sorry for the incomplete statement, I wanted to save current output generated by your suggested script. I tried but I unable to save this in csv or excel format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should help. The values of column 2 are converted according to the logic of the `percent_to_float` function. As for other columns, no custom converter specified, for there are strings anyway.

```py
import pandas as pd

def percent_to_float(s: str) -> float:
    if s.endswith('%'):
        return float(s.removesuffix('%')) / 100.0
    else:
        return float(s)

df = pd.read_table('DEMO.dat',
                   sep='\s+',  # one or more spaces
                   converters={2: percent_to_float}
                  )
```

---

As for the expected output,

```py
for residue in ('ASN15', 'VAL2', ):
    print(residue,
          df.query(f'donor=="{residue}-Side" | donor=="{residue}-Main"').donor.count(),
          sep='\t- ')
```

---

To save the data into a [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), one can be straightforward:

```py
with open('results.csv', 'wt') as f_out:
    for residue in ('ASN15', 'VAL2', ):
        f_out.write(','.join((
            residue,
            str(df.query(f'donor=="{residue}-Side" | donor=="{residue}-Main"').donor.count())
            )) + '\n')
```

Saving the data into an MS Excel (XLSX) file is a bit more tricky. Although the format is open, it's complicated and poorly documented. You can use [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/), for instance. The following code is based on [Tutorial 1](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html).

```py
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook: xlsxwriter.Workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('results.xlsx')
worksheet: xlsxwriter.Worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row: int
residue: str
for row, residue in enumerate(('ASN15', 'VAL2', )):
    worksheet.write(row, 0, residue)
    worksheet.write(row, 1, df.query(f'donor=="{residue}-Side" | donor=="{residue}-Main"').donor.count())

workbook.close()
```

Comment: It's working properly after done some small editing. (Capital to small letter)                                                                       xlsxwriter.Workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook---> xlsxwriter.workbook = xlsxwriter.workbook             worksheet: xlsxwriter.Worksheet = worksheet: xlsxwriter.worksheet =